# Should I ask this as one question or as several questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Here's a list of questions that I was going to put into a single question about adapting the X-Files into an RPG campaign:

> - Should I let the players take the roles of Mulder and Scully (and Krycek) or of custom characters working alongside them?
> - How should I handle scenarios that rely on finding very specific clues or understanding obscure connections? Mulder and Scully might be smart enough to find them but most real people won't be, especially not when given only a few hours.
> - How do I handle the fact that some players may know part of the story arc from the TV series?
> - Are there rulesets that would particularly favor an X-Files game? I'm not looking for modern-day RPGs in general but for games with specific mechanics that would be suitable for this setting.

I then realized that several of these may well be more useful as completely separate questions with no mention of the X-Files. However, splitting them up into separate questions would not give me any of the X-Files-specific advice that I'm also looking for.

Should I split these questions up or keep them as one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that you could pretty easily split them up into different questions, while still retaining X-files specific advice where it would be the most helpful. Perhaps phrase them as

- What problems might I run into by letting PCs play the main characters in a television show setting?
- What is the best way of helping players figure out clues to the main storyline without making it painfully obvious?
- How do I make a game challenging for a group where one or more players know the storyline?
- Are there rulesets that would particularly favor an X-Files game?

In each of the questions you could mention your specific setting as an example of your inquiry. This way main answers can be general, but can then be specified to your situation. Looks like a good list of questions, I look forward to seeing what others have to say on the scenario.

Comment: Perhaps link each separate question to one another so that way there is a common link between the two of them. It also might help inform other answers.

Comment: I like the idea of using a specific setting as an example in the questions. That should allow for good answers without making them less useful to others.